# How to pass column name in variable in mongo collection

Tags: mongodb

I want to pass collection's column name using variable. For example
var column="name" 
Db.student.find({column:value})

Getting error

Comment: This might be specific to the programming language and library you are using. Feel free to give more details of your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript (ECMAScript 2015) you can use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

```
const query = {[column]: value}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the key of the query object dynamically:

```
var name = req.params.name;
var value = req.params.value;
var query = {};
query[name] = value;
collection.findOne(query, function (err, item) { ... });
```

When you do {name: value}, the key is the string 'name' and not the value of the variable name.

Comment: What exactly the meaning of these two                                                                                  var name = req.params.name;
var value = req.params.value;